# convert powershell script to c #

Tags: c#, powershell

Good day to all!
Do not tell me if it is possible to translate the powershell script into c#

```
$server = "ServerName";

$sessions = query user /server:$server | select -skip 1;

foreach ($line in $sessions) 
{ 
    $line = -split $line;


    if ($line.length -eq 8)
    {

        $state = ($line[3]).Length;


        $sessionid = $line[2]; 
        $idletime = $line[4];
     } else {

        $state = ($line[2]).Length;


        $sessionid = $line[1]; 
        $idletime = $line[3];
    }

    if ($state -eq 4) 
    { 
        logoff $sessionid /server:$server /v
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then show some effort, meaning the source you have so far, as [example].

Answer (score 0):

Any code can be converted to any language, but you need to know both languages. In case you wanna run same powershell code from a C# code check the following solution:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/